# Application crashes on resuming when using GoogleApiClient

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-api-client, android-googleapiclient

i'm using GoogleApiClient in my android app and experiencing a crash when my app is resuming.

The code looks like this:

**MainActivity signature:**

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener, Android.Gms.Location.ILocationListener
```

*OnCreate*

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    App.Initialize();
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    await InitializeGoogleApis();
}
```

*Google API Initialization*

```
private async Task InitializeGoogleApis()
{
    // Construct api client and request for required api's
    googleApiClientBuilder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
       .AddApi(LocationServices.API)
       .EnableAutoManage(this, this);

    // Connect to google play services
    googleApiClient = await googleApiClientBuilder
        .BuildAndConnectAsync();

    // Request location api and set common properties
    googleLocationRequest = new LocationRequest()
        .SetPriority(LocationRequest.PriorityHighAccuracy)
        .SetInterval(1000)
        .SetFastestInterval(1000);

    // Set location changed listener
    await LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.RequestLocationUpdatesAsync(googleApiClient, googleLocationRequest, this);
}
```

*OnResume and OnDestroy*:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
}

protected override async void OnDestroy()
{
    base.OnDestroy();

    if (googleApiClient != null)
        await LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.RemoveLocationUpdatesAsync(googleApiClient, this);
}
```

I have all exceptions turned on but there [is no exception description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNDCR.png)

The app is always crashing when I try to resume. When it crashes, it's put in the background and when I try to resume it again it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a hacky way around this, I left all of my implementation the same, just added these functions to my main activity

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    base.OnStop();

    if (googleApiClient != null)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.Dispose();
        googleApiClient.StopAutoManage(this);
        googleApiClient.Disconnect();
        googleApiClient.Dispose();
        googleApiClient = null;
    }
}

protected override async void OnRestart()
{
    base.OnRestart();
    await InitializeGoogleApis();
}
```

I forcebly stop GoogleApiClient and reinitialize it again inside my OnRestart function. So basicaly that solves my problem.